# Реестр Windows x64 и x86

Tags: windows, com, x86-64, c++

В чем различие между реестром в Windows x64 и Windows x86? Я регистрирую 32-битный компонент в Windows 7 x64. После регистрации его не получается вызвать, при этом регистрация проходит успешно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дело в том, что нельзя вызвать 32-битный компонент из 64-битного кода. В Windows x64 существует отдельная ветка для 32-битных компонентов. При регистрации 32-битного компонента в системе к его ключу добавляется префикс, т.е. получается, что он регистрируется под другим ключом.